# How to allow users to send issues via e-mail to MantisBT?

Tags: email, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, mantis

In http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_issue-tracking_systems#Input_interfaces it says, that Mantis allows Input via mail.

I checked `config_defaults_inc.php` for associated settings, but could not find them. How can I allow my users to send issues to my MantisBT instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to install the EmailReporting plugin to enable this feature. You can download the plugin from https://github.com/mantisbt-plugins/EmailReporting

Installation of the plugin is straightforward, but configuration can be done only from the plugin page. Please make sure that you read the README before using the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MantisHub (MantisBT as a Service), email reporting is included as part of the gold and platinum plans:
http://www.mantishub.com/

You can find the documentation of the feature at:
http://support.mantishub.com/hc/en-us/articles/204273585-Using-Email-Reporting